# A question on dynamical system's focus values on its center manifold

Tags: dynamical-systems, vector-fields

I have recently come across this problem involving the center focus of dynamical systems of a parameter vector field related to center manifold:

> We define a vector field on $ R^3 $ given by:
>
> $ {x_1}' = -x_1+{x_3}^2 $
>
> $ {x_2}' = x_3+{x_1}^2 $
>
> $ {x_3}' = -x_2 +a{x_2}^3+b{x_2}^2x_3 + cx_2{x_3}^2+d{x_3}^3$
>
> Where a,b,c,d are real parameters
>
> We are asked to find a necessary and sufficient condition on the parameters a,b,c,d for which the first focus/Lyapunov value restricted to the center manifold is not zero

The fact that I am dealing with $ R^3 $ is puzzling me and my problem here is I cannot really find the restriction of this system to its center manifold so this i where I am stuck and where I need the help. Thanks all helpers

Comment: It seems that there is a [solution](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Andronov-Hopf_bifurcation#Multi-dimensional_Case) without finding center manifold (at least explicitly). Though it's quite tedious, it might work in your case.

Comment: Thanks for this it does help but actually i was more interested in center manifold if you could show me that i would appreciate it

Comment: Although a great reference was mentioned in answer (I also recommend to take a look at Meiss' book _Differetial dynamical systems_), you would help others a lot if you will post what you've already done -- i.e., analysis of equilibria (there might be several of them) and analysis of parameters when Andronov-Hopf bifurcation happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is impossible to get the center manifold of a vector field, even some simple vector fields. But you can get the system restricted to a patch of the center manifold around the center equibirium point, and you can refer to chapter "center manfiold for vector fields", in the book "introduction to applied nonlinear dynamical systems and chaos"-by Stephen Wiggins. Maybe it can help you.